# Task-scheduler: cannot view/edit/run the tasks CREATED BY OTHER WINDOWS USER

Tags: scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler, task-scheduler

We created tasks using one windows user and we configured it in such a way that service account will run the task but not the windows user.

Now the issue is when I login with other windows user I am not able to view the tasks created by 1st user.